# What rule was used and we changed the sign in this inv multiplicative mod?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I don't understand the exact steps the following statement is using in regards to what is the multiplicative inverse of $13 \mod 40$

> One can find a multiplicative inverse of $13$ by observing that:
> $13 \cdot 3 = 39 \equiv -1 \mod 40$  **(a)**
> Hence
> $13 \cdot (-3) \equiv 1 \mod 40$ **(b)**
> So $-3$ is a multiplicative inverse of $13 \mod 40$

Now I do understand (a).
I also understand that $13 \cdot (-3) = - 39 = -39 + 40 = 1 \equiv 1 \mod 40$  **(c)**

What is not clear to me is what rule is used so that we switch the multiplication from $3$ to $-3$.
$3$ and $-3$ are not multiplicative inverses $\mod 40$.
Was there some rule I am not aware or was what I described in **c** used?

I just would like to know if there is a specific rule used that allowed to go from $-1$ to $1$ by changing the sign in the lhs of the mod

Comment: It is just multiplication by $-1$ on both sides.

Comment: @arbashn:  So congruence follows the same rules as equality? I thought that the usage of the term equality in regards to congruence was a more general term/analogy, so it did not occur to me that I could multiply by −1. Somehow I can not map in my mind congruence and equality as really equivalent

Comment: @Jim You can check yourself, really. $$a\equiv-b\pmod{40}$$ means by definition that $a-b$ is divisible by $40$. Does it automatically follow from there that $(-a)-(-b)$ is divisible by $40$? If so, you can freely swap signs on both sides. Does it follow that $7a-7b$ is divisible by $40$? If so, it works to multiply both sides by $7$. Does it follow that $(a-6)-(b-6)$ is divisible by $40$? If so, you can subtract $6$ from both sides. And so on ...

Comment: Just as for equations, congruences are preserved by scaling both sides by an integer $\,k.\,$ by the Congruence Product Rule in the linked dupe. In particular we can negate congruences by scaling them by $-1$.

Comment: Or, a direct proof: $\,a-b = -(-a-(-b))\,$ so $\,n\mid a-b\iff n\mid -a-(-b),\,$ i.e. $\!\bmod n\!:$ $\,a\equiv b\iff -a\equiv -b.\,$  Or, we can tweak the linked proof of the Congruence Sum Rule to get a Congruence Difference Rule $\,A\equiv a,\, B\equiv b\Rightarrow A-B\equiv a-b.\,$ This yields the Negation Rule as the special case $\,A\equiv 0\equiv a,\,$ i.e. it yields $\,B\equiv b\Rightarrow -B\equiv -b\ \ $